# Next13 send client data through server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm dealing with some problems sending client data through the server on Next13 with app directory. So in general, I need to send info as device, isBot, browser, ua, os, cpu, engine and IP. I'm accessing those in my middleware, but it's executed to many times. Either I have to implement it in layout, or to make sure that it's executed only once (when user loads the page), or even when client changes the page. My current approach will execute when lang is available. However when user loads the page first time, it will execute other pages to load that are in my navigation and it will log it 5-6 times. Also, when user hovers the page next will load it before that.

here is my middleware:

```
const urlLang = languages.find((lang) => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${lang}`));

    const shouldExecuteMiddleware = config.matcher.some((pattern) => {
        const regex = new RegExp(pattern);
        return regex.test(req.nextUrl.pathname);
    });

    if (shouldExecuteMiddleware && urlLang) {
        const { device, isBot, browser, ua, os, cpu, engine } = userAgent(req);

        let ipAddress;

        if (req.headers.get('x-forwarded-for')) {
            ipAddress = (req.headers.get('x-forwarded-for') as string).split(', ')[0];
        } else if (req.headers.get('x-real-ip')) {
            ipAddress = req.headers.get('x-real-ip') as string;
        } else if (req.headers.get('x-client-ip')) {
            ipAddress = req.headers.get('x-client-ip') as string;
        } else {
            ipAddress = 'IP not valid';
        }
    }
```

How to use them in layout but not passing them as a props? Any ideas?